# JQuery UI Autocomplete shows [Object object] in textbox while scrolling the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a `textbox` on a form that I have attached a `jquery ui autocomplete` to it like this :

```
$("#recieverNumber").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'Get',
                url: myServiceUrl,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('input.suggest-user').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  // hide loading image
                    var result = [];
                    data.forEach(function (value, index) {
                        result.push({ value: value, label: value.Name });
                    });
                    response(result);
                },
                error: function (data, err, message) {
                    $('input.suggest-user').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');

                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () { }
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            recievers.push(ui.item.value);
            notifyRecieversChanged();
            $(this).val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you can see I am getting its source from a server side service and then I build an array of objects with value and label.Everything is working fine but whenever there are more than one item in autocomplete menu and I want to scroll the menu to find the desirable item I see `[Object object]` in `textbox` instead of the label of the item.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You could post json response sample. BTW, I guess that missing comma after `url: myServiceUrl` is a typo?

Comment: Yes its a typo :) data is a list of contacts something like this : {{Name:'John',Tel:'111111111'},{Name:'Sara',Tel:'2222222222'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

First argument in `response` array is rendered in select dropdown, while the `value` (as second argument) is supposed to be returned when selection is made. If `value` is not defined, then `label` will be returned instead.

**Json** (referred to comment below the question):

```
{
    {Name:'John',Tel:'111111111'},
    {Name:'Sara',Tel:'2222222222'}
}
```

Try:

**Success callback**:

```
success : function(data){
    data.forEach(function (value, index) {
        // add 'data', remove 'value', select will be rendered from 'label'
        // If you want display value (Tel) after selection, use this:
        // result.push({label:value.Name, value:value.Tel, data:value });
        result.push({label:value.Name, data:value });
    });
    response(result);
}
```

**Select callback**:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    // use 'data' instead of value:
    recievers.push(ui.item.data);
    // ...
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/wyjqu668/)

---

Eventually, you could make it much simpler, by echoing already prepared Json.

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        array(
            'label'=>'John',
            'data'=>array(
                'Name'=>'John', 'Tel'=>'111111111'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'label'=>'Sara',
            'data'=>array(
                'Name'=>'John', 'Tel'=>'2222222222'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And then:

```
success: function (data) {
    response(data);
}

// ...

select: function (event, ui) {
    recievers.push(ui.item.data);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As you can see value has to be an object because when user selects an Item from menu I am adding its value (Name and Tel) to an array to bind it to a grid view.

Comment: Thanks :) I always forget the beauty of a dynamic language like `javascript` where you can add properties/fields and methods on the fly :) I will check to see if everything is working properly and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. When scrolling through the list I saw "[object object]" in my textfield. 
Overriding the default focus behaviour worked for me:

```
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus